# Al pulsar en fragment pulso la activity

Tags: android, fragment

Tengo el problema de que al crear todos mis `fragments` los botones de la `activity` siguen funcionando, es decir, al estar en uno de los `fragments` si le doy en alguna lado de la pantalla donde hay un botón en la `activity` este se pulsa.

el archivo java del fragment lo dejo vacio y lo hago todo desde el `activity`, puede que sea ese el motivo?

```
public class LogoutFragment extends Fragment {

public LogoutFragment() { }

    final View vista = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_logout, container, false );

     logoutNo = vista.findViewById( R.id.imageButton3 );
     logoutYes = vista.findViewById( R.id.imageButton2 );

    logoutYes.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            // auth.signOut();
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .signOut( getActivity() )
                    .addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            // ...
                        }
                    } );

            Toast.makeText( getActivity(), "Te has deslogueado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);

        }
    } );

    logoutNo.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                    remove( getFragmentManager().findFragmentById( R.id.contenedor ) ).commit(); //  codigo para salir del fragment hacia la activity
        }
    } );

    return vista;
```

en el main para elegir los fragments tengo esto, no se si puede venir por ahí

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        Toast.makeText( context, R.string.very_soon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace( R.id.contenedor, new GalleryFragment() ).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        Toast.makeText( context, R.string.very_soon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

    }  else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace( R.id.contenedor, new LogoutFragment() ).commitAllowingStateLoss();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById( R.id.drawer_layout );
    drawer.closeDrawer( GravityCompat.START );
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El "problema" que comentas es precisamente por lo que intuyes, en realidad tienes los listener de botones en la actividad y **el fragment se encuentra contenido dentro de la Activity.**

Debes cambiar la lógica para que los botones solo se activen al dar clic en el `fragment`.

El layout `fragment_logout.xml` que carga tu Fragment debe tener estos botones y en el mismo fragment debes obtener sus referencias y asignar `listeners` para realizar la acción de clic

---

Este es un ejemplo de como obtener la referencia de un botón (debe estar contenido en el layout) y asignar su `OnClickListener` :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //Infla layout que contiene botones.
   View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_logout, container, false );
    //Obtiene referencias.
    Button mybutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAgregar);
    mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            //Define acción de botón.

            }
        });


    return view
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero haciendo los cambios que me has comentado me pasa lo mismo, los tiros pueden venir por el selector de fragments del MainAcitivty?